# Altair/HoloVis Panel - Multiple Select not working

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair, holoviews

I am using Altair to generate my plots (As i need the linked bar-chart selection) and Panel to create my dashboard. I have two dropdowns, where the values in the second are conditional on the value in the first.

When I use a Single Select dropdown the dashboard works as expected. However when I try and use any Mulitiple select widget I get no data rendered on my chart

```
import panel as pn
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data
import datetime as dt
from altair import datum

alt.renderers.enable('default')
pn.extension('vega')

data = pd.read_excel('randomtestdata.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Parent Location','Location','Alert Definition','Alert Type','Initiated Date'])

df = df[(df['Parent Location'] == 'Zone 1') | (df['Parent Location'] == 'Zone 2' )| (df['Parent Location'] == 'Zone 3' )]

df.rename(columns={'Parent Location': 'ParentLocation'},
          inplace=True, errors='raise')

source = df

title = '##Dashboard'
subtitle = 'This is a test dashboard. Use widgets below to show desired chart.'

_locations = {
    'Zone 1': source.loc[source['ParentLocation'] == 'Zone 1']['Location'].unique().tolist(),
    'Zone 2'  : source.loc[source['ParentLocation'] == 'Zone 2']['Location'].unique().tolist(),
    'Zone 3': source.loc[source['ParentLocation'] == 'Zone 3']['Location'].unique().tolist()
}

zone = pn.widgets.Select(
    name = 'Select a Zone',
    value ='Zone 1', 
    options =['Zone 1', 'Zone 2', 'Zone 3']
)

#The following does not work
location = pn.widgets.MultiSelect(
    name = 'Select a Location',
    value =[True], 
    options =_locations[zone.value]
)

# The following does works:
# location = pn.widgets.Select(
#     name = 'Select a Location',
#     value = _locations[zone.value][0], 
#     options =_locations[zone.value]
# )


date_range_slider = pn.widgets.DateRangeSlider(
    name='Date range to consider',
    start=dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1), end=dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    value=(dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1))
)

@pn.depends(zone.param.value, location.param.value, date_range_slider.param.value, watch=True)
def get_plot(zone, location, date_range): # start function

    df = source
    df['Initiated Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Initiated Date']) # format date as datetime
    
    start_date = date_range_slider.value[0] 
    end_date = date_range_slider.value[1] 
    mask = (df['Initiated Date'] > start_date) & (df['Initiated Date'] <= end_date)
    df = df.loc[mask] 
    
    selection2 = alt.selection_single(fields=['Alert Type'])

    chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(
        color="#0c1944", 
        opacity=0.8).encode(
        x=alt.X('Alert Type:O', scale=alt.Scale(domain=source['Alert Type'].unique())),
        y='count(Alert Type)').transform_filter(
        (datum.Location == location) 
    ).add_selection(selection2)
    
    chart2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(
        color="#0c1944", 
        opacity=0.8).encode(
        x='Alert Definition', 
        y='count(Alert Definition)').transform_filter(
        (datum.Location == location) 
    ).transform_filter(selection2)
            
    return (chart|chart2)

@pn.depends(zone.param.value, watch=True)
def _update_locations(zone):
    
    locations = _locations[zone]
    location.options = locations
    location.value = locations[0]
    
    return

pn.Row(
    pn.Column(title, subtitle, zone, location, date_range_slider,
    get_plot )
)
```

[image: Example of blank chart]

Random test data:
https://github.com/KWSpittles/testdata

Comment: Can you provide sample data? I think it is a burden to prepare the data by myself when I think about the answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, i have created some random test data here for your convenience - https://github.com/KWSpittles/testdata

Comment: Since I am short on time, I noticed two things: first, the column name of 'Alert__Definition' is different from the 'Alert_Definition' in the code(_is space), and second, in the data you provided, the 'Alert Definition' is all NA. Please check if this is the cause.

Comment: Good suggestions! Also, OP, please edit the title to say HoloViz rather than Holovis, so that people searching will find this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the title - Neither of these are the issue :( I have also edited my code to show exactly the problem.

Comment: The error is still not resolved, but the code in Altair's graphing can resolve the error: there is no `add_selection` in the second chart and the `transform_filter` is set twice. and the data frame in the first scale name is `df`, not `source`.

Comment: I don't believe there should be an add_selection, the second graph needs 2 transform filters. One from the selection in 'chart' and one from the locations on the dropdown. Also they should both be df not source.

Comment: If you need two types of filters, don't you need two lines in `transform_fileter`? Also, is it necessary to have multiple selections for the location? It worked correctly with a single selection, and I've expanded it to Colab, so please check it out.

Comment: The second selection is so that I can click on the first chart to transform the data in the second chart. Unfortunately the code you provided does not achieve that. Also this is a single select on Location whereas I require a MultiSelect option. Thanks

Comment: If it is the second graph selection, do we need to add a new selection? That's about all I can do.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because you are filtering you Altair charts using

```py
.transform_filter(
    datum.Location == location
)
```

which allows filtering for a single value. When you pass a list of multiple values you need to instead use `indexof` like this

```py
.transform_filter(
    f'indexof({location}, datum.Location) != -1'
)
```